# How to mark unseen last unread message S22.imap

Tags: c#, imap

How read last unread message from mail box and after mark this message "Unseen"

I use s22.imap.dll

```
ImapClient Client = new ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", 993, "My_Username",
    "My_Password", true, AuthMethod.Login);

// Get a list of unique identifiers (UIDs) of all unread messages in the mailbox.
uint[] uids = Client.Search( SearchCondition.Unseen() );

// Fetch the messages and print out their subject lines.
foreach(uint uid in uids) {
    MailMessage message = Client.GetMessage(uid);

 Console.WriteLine(message.Subject);
}

// Free up any resources associated with this instance.
Client.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 5):

First get uid last unread message:

```
var lastUid = Client.Search( SearchCondition.Unseen().Last() );
```

and read this message;

```
MailMessage message = Client.GetMessage( lastUid );
```

To mark this message as "Unseen":

```
Client.RemoveMessageFlags( lastUid, null, MessageFlag.Seen );
```

See more on: [ImapClient.RemoveMessageFlags Method](http://smiley22.github.io/S22.Imap/Documentation/html/M_S22_Imap_ImapClient_RemoveMessageFlags.htm)