# Get LastUID from message using s22.dll and c#

Tags: c#, email, imap

i followed the article [How to mark unseen last unread message S22.imap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20248399/how-to-mark-unseen-last-unread-message-s22-imap)

but i am not able to get the UID of my messge.

```
long abc = 0;

            using (ImapClient Client = new ImapClient("abc.com", 143, "abc@abc.com", "password", S22.Imap.AuthMethod.Login, false))
            {
                IEnumerable<uint> uids = Client.Search(SearchCondition.Unseen());

                IEnumerable<MailMessage> messages = Client.GetMessages(uids, FetchOptions.Normal);
                foreach (MailMessage msg in messages)
                {
                    string msgFrom = msg.From.ToString();
                    string To = msg.To.ToString();
                    string Subject = msg.Subject;

                    // here i want the UID of this messge "msg"
                    // so that i can use it in order to mark this
                    // message as marked.

                    abc = abc + 1;
                }
            }
```

how can i get this UID ?

Comment: seems like no one on stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to get what you want in S22.Imap, but here's how you would do it with [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) (another open source IMAP library for .NET):

```
long abc = 0;
using (ImapClient client = new ImapClient ()) {
    client.Connect ("abc.com", 143, false);
    client.Authenticate ("abc@abc.com", "password");

    client.Inbox.Open (FolderAccess.ReadWrite);

    var uids = client.Inbox.Search (SearchQuery.NotSeen);

    foreach (var uid in uids) {
        var message = inbox.GetMessage (uid);
        var msgFrom = message.From.ToString ();
        var to = message.To.ToString ();
        var subject = message.Subject;

        // mark the message as read/seen
        client.Inbox.AddFlags (uid, MessageFlags.Seen, true);

        abc = abc + 1;
    }
}
```

For what it's worth, S22.Imap seems to be an abandoned project (with lots of bugs that aren't getting fixed), you should really look into using MailKit instead - it has a lot more users, more features, fewer bugs and is actively maintained (and I say that as someone who has actually contributed patches to S22.Imap).

Hope that helps.